# Python SQLAlchemy memory leak on Linux

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I wrote a script that iterates through a large database table.  (~150K rows.)  To avoid using too much memory I'm using this [windowed_query method](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes/WindowedRangeQuery).  My script goes something like this:

```
query = db.query(Table)

count = 0
for row in windowed_query(query, Table.id, 1000):

    points = 0

    # +100 points for a logo
    if row.logo_id:
        points += 100

    # +10 points for each image
    points += 10 * len(row.images) #images is a SQLAlchemy one-to-many relationship

    #...The script continues with much of the same...

    row.points = points
    db.add(row)

    count += 1
    if count % 100 == 0:
        db.commit()
        print count

request.db.commit()
```

When trying to run it on a CentOS server, it makes it through 9000 rows before getting killed by the kernel **because it's using ~2GB of memory**.

On my Mac development environment, it works like a charm, even though it's running on exactly the same version of Python (2.7.3), SQLAlchemy (0.7.8), and psycopg2 (2.4.5).

Using memory_profiler for some simple debugging:  On Linux, each piece of code that queries the database increased the memory a small amount, with the growth never stopping.  On Mac, the same thing happened, but after growing ~4MB it leveled off.  It's as if on Linux nothing is being garbage collected.  (I even tried running gc.collect() every 100 rows.  Didn't do anything.)

Does anybody have a clue what is happening?

Comment: Perhaps you're suffering from this bug? http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t649192-psycopg2-and-large-queries.html

Comment: But with `windowed_query` the largest query is 1000 rows, so `fetchone` using the memory of `fetchall` doesn't explain 2GB of memory use.

Comment: Aaahhhh.... I figured it out.  I'm using Pyramid, and had the debug toolbar enabled.  After disabling it, the memory usage plateaued at 73MB.  Problem solved!

Comment: @TheronLuhn Hey, glad you solved this! Since your question is solved, feel free to [post an answer to your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and mark it as "Accepted" (click the big green checkmark). This helps other people know that your problem was solved :)

Comment: Alright, I will do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out Pyramid's debugtoolbar was enabled, which was the reason for the high memory use.  I disabled it and the script worked like a charm.

Comment: Yup, most of the debugging toolbars keep the sql which is sent to server for later debugging (also had similar fun with Flask's debug toolbar).